# How to explicitly say that the application doesn't support LDPI devices

Tags: android

How can I make it so that my application is seen on the Android Market only by devices with mdpi and hdpi densities.

There is the `<supports-screens>` tag and there is the `anyDensity` parameter but I don't see how I can say what I want. If I set anyDensity to false, what does that mean? Where do I specify which densities I do support?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the [<compatible-screens>](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) tag in <manifest>. It allows to enumerate supported sizes and dpis:

```
..
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
..
```

All other combinations will be disabled.

Comment: I realize you're just giving an example, but maybe you should include mdpi in the list, in case someone takes this example as it is and only want to exlucude ldpi devices?

Answer (score 1):

The small screens represent LVGA. If you declare `android:smallScreens="false"` in your manifest it indicates that your application will not support LVGA.

If you are compiling your application with minimumsdk/targetsdk of 1.5 SDK then by default these values will be **false** in the else case these values will be **true**. So in this case you need to specify that your application will not support LVGA by declaring smallscreens attribute as **false**.

Comment: If you look here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range you can see that there are ldpi devices that have normal screen. I want to know how to say that I don't support those devices (e.g ldpi + normal screen)

Comment: i don't think you have stimulator or device support for WQVGA and FWQVGA screens. i have not heard any popular devices running on the above two densities. Do you know any device that runs on the above screen sizes?

Comment: Well, if you look here http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html you can see that currently there are 0.4% ldpi devices with normal screens. It's a small percentage but, if I don't want to take the trouble to customize the graphics and the layouts for these devices, I need to exclude them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

See here for details:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: I already knew what it said in the link but this doesn't answer my question. You can disable support for small/normal/large screens but there is no way to disable support for ldpi devices.